# How to call the overridden Delete link (Del) in a Related List of Account detail page, which is displayed using “nooverride=1" parameter in the URL?

Tags: related-list, button-overrides

I have overridden the standard "View" of the Account detail page with a custom Visualforce page.  When I need to display the Account detail page, I use the "nooverride=1" parameter in the URL to display it and bypass the override.

I have also overridden Salesforce’s standard Delete link in a Related List of the Account detail page, by creating a second Visualforce page.

The problem I am having is, when I clicked the overridden Delete link in the Related List, the second Visualforce page is never called.  The standard Salesforce Delete was called instead.  I think this is happening because the Account Detail page was displayed with the “nooverride=1" parameter.  Thus, no overrides were allowed (and my overridden Delete link in the Related List was not called).

Can someone give me some pointers as to how to call the overridden Delete link on a Related List, when the Delete link is clicked? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

~Shirley

Comment: Please expose the relevant portion of your VF page

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can hide the delete botton and create a custom delete button instead?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @highfive Actually I think what @ ling is proposing will solve the problem, since the custom button will call the delete-vf page without override.

Comment: Agreed @UweHeim. I think as ling is giving an suggestion good to move this as a comment and if it helps then can give a detailed answer.

Comment: @ling, creating a custom delete button will work, but the standard Del link will still be there on the Related List.  Does anyone know of a way to hide the Del link?

Comment: I guess there is not a way to override anything on a detail page, if the detail page is displayed by using"nooverride=1" parameter in the URL.  If anyone know of a way, please let me know.  Thanks.